# Android Application Code Tracing

Tags: android, adt, trace

How can I trace an android application from ADT? I applied some test cases on an android application and for post analysis, I need to record which lines of application code is executed during each test case. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you talking about debugging?

Comment: No, I applied some test case on an application, I need to record which lines of application code is executed during each test case.

Comment: From [Android Dev site](http://developer.android.com/) look at [Using DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) and [Profiling with Traceview and dmtracedump](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)

Comment: Thanks Onik. I did it before but it just trace method calls. I need a line-by-line tracing of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add Log after each line

Log.d("line numbers",output of each line)

Example:

```
 int key=1;
for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
{
  if(i==1) 
  {
        key=key+1;
       Log.d("line 6",String.valueOf(key));
  }
  if(i==5)
    {key=key+5;
          Log.d("line 10",String.valueOf(key));
    }
   else
       Log.d("line 12","in else");

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to use hard coding. In this way, every time I change my code, I need to update all this logs. In addition, what about applications with thousands of code?!

Answer (score 0):

If your device has root, you can use method trace from adb 
From Eclipse menu:
Window -> Show View -> Other...
Than from Android group choose Devices.
If you can see your devices running applications packages - select your package, and click on "Start Method Profiling". Select "Trace based profiling", and perform your actions. When your test scenario is completed click on "Stop Method Profiling", and trace will be displayed. Method trace allows you to trace all method calls on timeline and list.

Otherwise (if you can't see packages) - as VaDtHyAvAtH suggested, use Logs.

Comment: Thanks Kuba. In this way I can trace just method calls but I want to trace line by line! what can I do about that?

Comment: I never needed to track application on that level. If not method trace, Logs come next, but I see you don't want to use them.

So it looks, like I can't help you.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that my only choice is Log.